# 質問一覧で質問冒頭部が表示されないケースがある

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

質問一覧画面では質問タイトル＋本文冒頭が表示されますが、下記投稿では本文部分がまったく表示されていません。例えば [facebookタグ一覧](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/facebook) ページなど。

[facebookの認証画面が一瞬だけ現れて-すぐに消える](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/4653/)

[image: 一覧のスクリーンショット]

該当投稿の1文字目が、全角空白になっているせいでしょうか？

---

再現環境：

- Firefox 35.0.1 / Windows 7

Comment: ブラウザを教えてくれますか？そして、テスト用に[このリンク先に](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions?page=2&sort=newest)「Facebook」を検索すれば現象が見えます。

Comment: @jmac 再現ブラウザ情報を追記しました。ただHTML文書上に情報が無いため、本件はサーバ側の問題と考えられます。

Comment: なんとブラウザ依存なのか！と思いましたがそうでもなさそうですね。。。HTMLソースを見ると「全角スペース、ドットx３」となっていました。

Comment: ２件目観測。くしくも同じ投稿者がバグを掘り当てました。 「[social.frameworkを使わないSNSの実装](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/6439/1)」。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

コミュニティのおかげさまでバグの再現ができて、二つのバグを治しました。

1. 投稿の頭文字がスペースの場合、諸略に入りません
2. 諸略はスペースではなく（regex: `\s`）、言葉の間に分けるので（regex: `\W`）、日本語で切れるところがない場合もあります。

スペースなしで200文字以上の文書がある場合、区切りが計算出来ないので同じ問題がおこりますが、通常はないと考えています。

---

Thanks to the community I've reproduced and fixed the two bugs that generated this behavior

1. Leading spaces should not have been included in the excerpt
2. The excerpt should break words at a word boundary (regex: `\W`) and not at every spacing character (regex: `\s`), since Japanese does not necessarily use spaces to separate words.

Please note that if you have more than 200 characters without any separator, the algorithm will still fail to find a place where to break the original text. Hopefully this is a very rare case.

Answer (score 2):

I can find it with this URL 
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook?sort=newest&pagesize=30

Windows 10 + Chrome 51.0.2704.103 m (64-bit)
Only open that URL and not logged in.

---

[image: StackOverflow Japan facebook tag]

---

[image: developer tools]

Comment: You can see same problem with this URL https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social-framework ; article title is "social.frameworkを使わないSNSの実装"

Comment: It's now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

[facebook](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook)のすべてのページを確認しましたが、このバグを再現できませんでした。再現するため、もうちょっと再現方法を教えてくれますか？

---

I've tried all the pages of the [facebook](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook) tag, but none of them had this problem. Can you provide more information on how to reproduce this behavior?